# How can I insert data into 2 different table in VB.net, I'm using MS Access as my db

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I'm having a trouble here using VS2010. I'm using a MS Access database.

I have 3 tables: `tblCustomers`, `tblBooking`, `tblRoom`

`tblCustomers` has these columns:

```
(1) Customer_ID
(2) Last_Name
(3) First_Name
(4) Age
(5) Address
(6) Contact
```

`tblBooking` has these columns:

```
(1) Book_No
(2) Customer_ID
(3) Day_In
(4) Day_Out
(5) Room_ID
```

`tblRoom` has these columns:

```
(1) Room_ID
(2) Room_Type
(3) Price
(4) Capacity
(5) Remarks
```

Now whenever I entered lname, fname, age, address, contact, choose a room type, capacity, put the preferred day_in and day_out and then click Book Now! It says it is successfully done. But when I look at my database, only the `tblCustomers` table are completely filled in.

Can anyone suggest something so that I can also fill in the `tblBooking` table.

I also did try joining them, but it doesn't work. Thanks in advance for the reply.

This is the code that I've made. The problem is, it is double inserting the information in tblCustomers table.

```
Private Sub bookBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles bookBtn.Click
    Try

        con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = HotelRsvp.accdb"
        query = "INSERT INTO tblCustomers (Last_Name, First_Name, Age, Address, Contact) VALUES ('" & lnametxtbx.Text.ToLower() & "', '" & fnametxtbx.Text.ToLower() & "', '" & agetxtbx.Text & "', '" & addtxtbx.Text.ToLower() & "', '" & contacttxtbx.Text & "')"
        query2 = "INSERT INTO tblBooking WHERE Customer_ID = tblCustomer.Customer_ID, Day_In = '" & dayIn.Value & "', Day_Out = '" & dayOut.Value & "', Room_ID = '" & rmIDlbl.Text & "'"


        dbUp = New OleDbCommand(query, con)
        dbUp2 = New OleDbCommand(query2, con)
        con.Open()
        dbUp.ExecuteNonQuery()
        dbUp2.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Successfully Booked.")
        lnametxtbx.Text = ""
        fnametxtbx.Text = ""
        agetxtbx.Text = ""
        addtxtbx.Text = ""
        contacttxtbx.Text = ""
        RmtypeCbx.ResetText()
        cpctyCbx.ResetText()
        rmIDlbl.Text = ""
        Pricelbl.Text = ""
        con.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        If Not IsNumeric(contacttxtbx.Text) Or Not IsNumeric(agetxtbx.Text) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Age, Contact Number or there's a blank.")
        Else
            'con.Open()
            dbUp = New OleDbCommand(query, con)
            dbUp.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MessageBox.Show("Successfully Booked.")
            con.Close()
        End If

    End Try
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Paste your source code please

Comment: Will do, wait. I'll code it again.

Comment: @CarlosLanderas, there's the source code bro.

Answer (score 0):

You `query2` is not specyfing values:

```
query2 = "INSERT INTO tblBooking WHERE Customer_ID = tblCustomer.Customer_ID, Day_In = '" & dayIn.Value & "', Day_Out = '" & dayOut.Value & "', Room_ID = '" & rmIDlbl.Text & "'"
```

as you do in query1. You are writing the where clause but you are not writing values.

```
query = "INSERT INTO tblCustomers (Last_Name, First_Name, Age, Address, Contact) VALUES ('" & lnametxtbx.Text.ToLower() & "', '" & fnametxtbx.Text.ToLower() & "', '" & agetxtbx.Text & "', '" & addtxtbx.Text.ToLower() & "', '" & contacttxtbx.Text & "')"
```

It should be:

```
query2 =

"INSERT INTO tblBooking (COL1,COL2,COL3) VALUES (VAL1,VAL2,VAL3) WHERE Customer_ID = tblCustomer.Customer_ID, Day_In = '" & dayIn.Value & "', Day_Out = '" & dayOut.Value & "', Room_ID = '" & rmIDlbl.Text & "'"
```

Comment: query2 = "INSERT INTO tblBooking (Customer_ID, Day_in, Day_Out, Room_ID) VALUES (*THIS IS THE PROBLEM PART, I can't select the Customer_ID from tblCustomers to be inserted into tblBooking's Customer_ID*)

Comment: You mean you dont have the id. You should make a query to the database to recover the client id one it has been inserted in db.

Comment: What I'm thinking is to get the Customer_ID from tblCustomers and then use it also at tblBooking, since they are the same. PK and FK.

Comment: Thats exactly what I said. Recover the ID from the inserted customer and use it in the booking table ;)

Comment: So, I'm going to use SELECT statement?

Comment: You need Select Statement or a stored procedure. What you prefer. Mark answer as accepted if I helped you please. The comments can be used for chatting