# Can't insert into acces db with .net

Tags: sql, vb.net

I used this site to get me on my way with the Insert command, however, i can't get it to work.
[How can I insert data into 2 different table in VB.net, I'm using MS Access as my db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424769/how-can-i-insert-data-into-2-different-table-in-vb-net-im-using-ms-access-as-m)
I got 3 tables, 1 with foodtypes, 1 with (basically) menus and 1 connecting table that connect the id of a menu with the ID's of sfoodtypes.
I try to use a query to create new menu's. however, a error occures: 
There is ; missing in the sql string

```
Str = "INSERT INTO tbl_rantsoen (Rantsoen, Voer, Gewicht) VALUES (cbRantsoen.text,   cbVoer.text, txtGewicht.text) VALUES (cbRantsoen.text, cbVoer.text, txtGewicht.text) WHERE RantsoenID = tblRantsoen.RantsoenID, Voer = '" & cbVoer.Text & "', Gewicht = '" & tbGewicht.Text & "'"
```

Now, i tried different places to place the ; but cant find the right spot. Can anyone help me?

The rest of the code::

EDIT:(and clean-up)
I made some changes based on the comments below, but i still get the ; missing error.

```
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    Dim cmd1 As New OleDbCommand
    Dim cmd2 As New OleDbCommand
    Dim Str As String
    Dim Str1 As String
    Dim Str2 As String
    Str = "INSERT INTO tbl_rantsoen (Rantsoen, Voer, Gewicht) VALUES (cbRantsoen.text, cbVoer.text, txtGewicht.text) VALUES (cbRantsoen.text, cbVoer.text, txtGewicht.text); " 'WHERE RantsoenID = tblRantsoen.RantsoenID, Voer = '" & cbVoer.Text & "', Gewicht = '" & tbGewicht.Text & "'"
    Str1 = "INSERT INTO tbl_voersoorten (VoerID, Voer) VALUES (cbVoer.text) WHERE Voer = '" & cbVoer.Text & "'"
    Str2 = "INSERT INTO tbl_rantsoenKoppel (VoerID, RantsoenID) VALUES() WHERE RantsoenID = tbl_rantsoenkoppel.FKRantsoenID AND VoerID = tbl_voersoorten.VoerID"
    connection.Open()
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(Str, connection)
    cmd1 = New OleDbCommand(Str1, connection)
    cmd2 = New OleDbCommand(Str2, connection)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: why are you use where caluse in insert statement?

Comment: Please review the allowed syntax for the INSERT INTO sql command text. Then rememeber that Access doesn't allow two commands to be executed together. You need two distinct ExecuteNonQuery

Comment: Hello, Thanks. I made some adjustments, deactived the Where statement but i still get the ; error on cmd.ExecuteNonQuery().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `WHERE` clauses in your `INSERT` command
and if you want execute more than one command in single `CommandText`you should to seperate them with `;`.
and finally:

```
Str  = "INSERT INTO tbl_rantsoen (Rantsoen, Voer, Gewicht) VALUES ('" & cbRantsoen.text & "', '"& cbVoer.text & "','"& txtGewicht.text & "')"
Str1 = "INSERT INTO tbl_voersoorten ( Voer) VALUES ('" & cbVoer.text & "')"
```

and for query Str3 you should to get related id from last two query and insert them into 3th query ;)

Comment: Hello,Thanks to you i did find one problem; the txtVoer should have been tbVoer.text, so that's fixed, i remover the WHERE clauses but still getting the same error.

Comment: Also, what do you mean with the Str3? Do you have some example code? I'm fairly new to .net even though i do have a little bit experience with SQL so i would think that that's SELECT FKVoerID, FKRantsoenID FROM tbl_rantsoenkoppel WHERE FKRantsoenID = tbl_rantsoen.RantsoenID AND FKVoerID = tbl_voersoorten.VoerID,

Comment: Woohoo, managed to get it saved into the first table using a textbox instead of combobox. All that left is the connection between the 2 tables(using the third table) and the use of the dropdown menu, but thats for the UPDATE function. I can fix that myself.

Answer (score 0):

Your INSERT Syntax is wrong. There cannot be a WHERE Clause.

```
INSERT INTO TableName (Column1,Column2,Colum3) VALUES(Value1,Value2,Value3);
```

If you are trying to change an existing record, try using the UPDATE Clause

```
UPDATE TableName SET Column1 = Value1 , Column2 = Value2, Column3 = Value3 WHERE Condition1 = Condition2 AND Condition3 = Condition4
```